# .htaccess rewrite: Remove parameter from url

Tags: regex, laravel, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I want to create subdomain from the first parameter of URL and then remove that parameter.

Desired result:

```
http://www.example.com/mystore          -> http://www.mystore.example.com
```

For this first I have created virtual host for mystore.example.com

Now I am trying to remove this mystore parameter from url.

I tried below changes in htaccess. Please check.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mystore/
```

Virtual Host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@gmail.com
    ServerName  mystore.example.local
    ServerAlias www.mytore.example.local

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Projectname/public/index.php/mystore

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess: This file is inside "public/" folder. This project is in laravel.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^mystore(/.*)?$ http://www.mystore.example.com$1 [NC,L,R=301,NE]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: @anubhava I tried after removing index.php/mystore from DocumentRoot, but still in url mystore not removed. When I run http://pragnastore.sliderstock.local/pragnastore this url it is not removing /pragnastore.

Comment: It should redirect to same but it just remove /pragnastore and show url like http://pragnastore.sliderstock.local

Comment: Yes I made this domain through virtual host. Originally it is "example.com/mystore" and I need to show storename as subdomain like, "mystore.example.com".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this link](https://likegeeks.com/dynamic-laravel-subdomain-routing/), I solved it with Laravel routing changes. So for this, First I created virtual host and then do this changes in my routing web.php

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.website.com'), function ($subdomain) {
    Route::get('/', 'controller@method');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use this rule in site root .htaccess of `www.example.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} pragnastore\.sliderstock\.local$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^pragnastore(/.*)?$ http://pragnastore.sliderstock.local$1 [NC,L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to use this rule **just below `RewriteEngine On`** line.

Comment: I edited my question with virtual host code. Please check. I was trying this in my local project. so I removed www and tried but it is not working
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mystore\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^mystore(/.*)?$ http://mystore.example.com$1 [NC,L,R=301,NE]

Comment: Is it possible that I can set expected URL with only using htaccess and not using virtual host?